# Am I creating an anti-Pattern? VBA arrangement of objects in a ContractManager class?

Tags: vba

## Structure for contract manager class

### Original approach - nested arrangement

In VBA I'm trying to build a contract manager class (e.g. to build contracts in MS Word) and I set out to do something like this:

`manager.contracts(cKey).specialConditions(sKey).markForReview`

*OR*

`Set foo = manager.contracts(cKey).specialConditions.Add`

But... it seems that in order to achieve this my arrangement of class objects is becoming nested in an increasingly complex way, e.g:

```
manager
 |-collectionClass1
    |-itemClassA
       |-collectionClass2
          |-itemClassB


'... and so on.
```

Is this optimal?

### Revised approach - flat structure

I'm wondering if it wold be better to flatten the arrangement of classes like this:

```
manager
 |-collectionClass1
 |-itemClassA
 |-collectionClass2
 |-itemClassB
```

... and do something like this instead:

`manager.markForReview(objSpecialCondition)`

*OR*

`Set foo = manager.specialConditionAdd(objContract)`

---

## Advantages & best practice?

I'm really looking for guidance, are there any specific pitfalls to be aware of?

It now seems to me that the flatter structure may have some advantages, (although I'm not sure if these are real or imagined):

- code reuse / flexibility
- easier to refactor / modify / maintain
- faster with less memory overhead

I think there are some disadvantages to a flatter structure, specifically it might become more difficult to see relationships between classes. The hierarchical structure of classes provides intuitive intellisense... and I think it makes it harder to introduce bugs? Although that could be addressed with *(additional?)* validation and use of descriptive variable / object names:

e.g. `contract` instead of `var1`

And I think a flatter structure that uses `keys` to find items in various collections would be workable, for example:

```
If reviewItems.Exists(specialCondition.ID) Then
    review(specialCondition)
End If
```

Comment: There is no one correct answer here, but if the arrangement of the items you're modelling with your classes is actually hierarchical then there's no obvious problem with mirroring that in your implementation.  Devil's in the details though as always.

Comment: Thanks, I also started to wonder if I should do both or a mixture of the two...

Comment: @SlowLearner Perhaps a better question for SuperUser/Code Review?

Comment: Yeah, I realise it doesn't quite fit the SE mould... CR requires working code and I think all the VBA gurus hang out here 

Comment: As Tim said, it really depends if you have something like the contract manager have another contract manager under him/her. You may want to add a variable to link this "Manager" in the class.

Comment: The contract manager is *supposed to be* a singleton...